# Create A Web Part For SharePoint Store

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-store

Since sandbox solutions are no longer supported in SharePoint Online how can a visual Web Part that will be made available on the SharePoint Store for purchasing be created?

Answer (score 1):

There's no real concept of Web part in SP Online.
You have two alternatives:

1. Create a SharePoint add-in containing an *app part*. But technically app parts have nothing to do with Web part. They're purely declarative (in a simple XML file) and are actually a simple IFrame pointing to a configured URL external to the current site.
2. Use the new SPFx (SharePoint Framework) tools to create a pure client-side "Web part". See [this link](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part).